# Linux Networking Driver With DMA Bus Mastering

Tags: c, driver, linux-device-driver

I am currently working on writing my first Linux Networking driver and it seems to be going fairly smoothly right now. My network device is going to create an Ethernet interface but forward the Ethernet frames over PCIe to a PCIe endpoint. My question has to do with reception of forwarded Ethernet frames from the PCIe endpoint destined for my interface.

What I would normally do would be to allocate a large DMA buffer, tell the endpoint with Bus Mastering capabilities where the buffer was, and allow it to DMA to that buffer. It would then send an interrupt to signal reception and I could copy the data into an `sk_buf`.

My question is this:
In LDD3, it says that I should be able to DMA directly to the `sk_buf` because all `sk_buf` are in DMA memory. When and where do I allocate this buffer and tell the Bus Master where it is located? Do I do it on initialization first, then once the Bus Master has written it's first `sk_buf` and interrupts me signalling reception, do I allocate a new buffer and write the new location? Can this only be done with poll enabled (I think its called NAPI) reception?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps the best way is to read `Documentation/DMA*.txt` files. Most probably you need the DMA sync API.